# PHP : Select overlapping date time ranges with time range overlapping day

Tags: php, date, time, range, overlap

I would like to know how to get date time ranges overlapping other date time ranges.
The particularity is that a date range **can have** time range overlapping two consecutive days.

For example i have a recurrent reservation the 01/01 and 02/01 beginning at 20:00 and finishing the next day at 02:00.

First day:

```
$start = '2017-01-01 20:00';
$end =   '2017-01-02 02:00';
```

Second day:

```
$start = '2017-01-02 20:00';
$end =   '2017-01-03 02:00';
```

Now i would like to know how to get reservations overlapping this reservation.

Note: All reservations can have or not time range overlapping day.

For example from a PHP point of view i have the following reservations :
Dates and times are represented here as string for readability. In reality they are DateTime.

```
//The reservation
$reservation= array(
   array(
      'day' => '2017-01-01',
      'time_range' => array('20:00', '23:59')
   ),
   array(
      'day' => '2017-01-02',
      'time_range' => array('00:00', '02:00')
   ),
);

//Other reservations
$reservations= array(
   //Reservation doesn't overlap
   array(
      'day' => '2017-01-01',
      'time_range' => array('18:00', '19:00')
   ),
   //Reservation overlaps
   array(
      'day' => '2017-01-01',
      'time_range' => array('21:00', '22:00')
   ),
   //Reservation overlaps
   array(
      array(
         'day' => '2017-01-01',
         'time_range' => array('23:00', '23:59')
      ),
      array(
         'day' => '2017-01-02',
         'time_range' => array('00:00', '01:00')
     ),
   ),
   ...
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @ishegg Yes i tried to compare  each time range of each day of the reservation to each time range of each day of all other reservations by `startA < endB && endA > startB`. But not sure if there is not a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use Objects to Make Life Easier

First, you really should simplify your structure. If you really DO have dateTimes everywhere, then reservations should look something more like:

```
class Reservation
{
    /** @var DateTime $start */
    public $start;
    /** @var DateTime $stop */
    public $stop;

    public function _construct(DateTime $start, DateTime $stop): void
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->stop = $stop;
    }

    public function isOverlapping(Reservation $reservation): bool
    {
        if ($reservation->start >= $this->start && $reservation->start <= $this->stop) {
            // starts during reservation
            return true;
        }

        if ($reservation->stop >= $this->start && $reservation->stop <= $this->stop) {
            // ends during reservation
            return true;
        }

        if ($reservation->start <= $this->start && $reservation->end >= $this->stop) {
            // $this is contained by $reservation
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Structuring your reservations this way will allow for some very simple solutions to your problem, like creating `RecurringReservation` which can generate an array of `Reservations` for a given date-range. Or a `Reservation->isToday()` method which could check the `$start` and `$stop` properties in cases where it wraps midnight.

## For the problem you ask for however:

```
class Reservation
{

    . . .

    public function anyOverlap(array $reservations): bool
    {
        foreach ($reservations as $checkMe) {
            if ($this->isOverlapping($checkMe)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$reservation = new Reservation(new DateTime('2017-01-01 20:00'), new DateTime('2017-01-02 02:00'));

$reservations = [
    new Reservation(new DateTime('2017-01-01 18:00'), new DateTime('2017-01-01 19:00')),
    new Reservation(new DateTime('2017-01-01 21:00'), new DateTime('2017-01-01 22:00')),
    new Reservation(new DateTime('2017-01-01 23:00'), new DateTime('2017-01-02 01:00')),
];

$reservation->anyOverlap($reservations); // true
```

## Edit: I just realised you want an array of overlapping reservations:

```
class Reservation
{

. . .

public function getOverlapping(array $reservations): array
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($reservations as $checkMe) {
            if ($this->isOverlapping($checkMe)) {
                $result[] = $checkMe;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

. . . 

$overlapping = $reservation->getOverlapping($reservations); // array
```

## One last addendum, use Generators for creating lists of results.

[Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) are awesome (when not misused). They offer very high performance when you need a list of results. They're only catch is that you have to pass their result straight into a loop to reap the benefits.

```
public function getOverlapping(array $reservations): Generator
{
    foreach ($reservations as $checkMe) {
        if ($this->isOverlapping($checkMe)) {
            yield $checkMe;
        }
    }
}

...

foreach($reservation->getOverlapping($reservations) as $overlap) {
    yellAtReceptionistFor($overlap); // ... or whatever 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed an interesting approach that i already have except for RecurrentReservation.

Answer (score -1):

You want to test an appointment start is between the other appointment start and end, then same for the appointment end.  If either is true, you have an overlap.